# How to display table in parts in command window in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-table

I have a table which consists of 17025 rows. When I try to display the table, the whole table displays. But I want it in small parts. How do I make it display in small parts.

Comment: Do you know which cells you want? Is there some other way of organizing the data, like a plot, or using conditional logic to weed out trivial answers?

Answer (score 0):

Type `more on` at the MATLAB command prompt. Subsequent output will be paused after every screenful.

Documentation: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/more.html

Answer (score 0):

I usually check my variables in these ways:

*Suppose that we have a variable called `A=rand(1000,1000)`.*

1.we can display a part of A by calling `A(127:130,241:243)`, to show the specific part of it.

```
>> A(127:130,241:243)

ans =

    0.8152    0.0674    0.5609
    0.1977    0.3906    0.6491
    0.3288    0.1255    0.7478
    0.9176    0.4253    0.5111
```

2.double click the name of the variable in the `Workspace`, so we could check it in `Variables`.

[image: pic1]

3.if your data only contain few columns, I recommend you to draw them in a figure and view them by dragging a `Data Cursor` in the picture.

[image: pic2]

SampleCode:

```
A=[1:1:200; 250:-1:51];
plot(A')
```

However, only the first option could display matrix on command window, but 2&3 is much faster since we don't know which part to display.